# VueJS - route.go doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, router, vue-router

When i try redirect to other router in watcher, console gives me this error:

Can somebody help me and tell why is this happening?

Thanks!

```
watch: {
   lifes : function() {
     console.log('lifes watcher work')
     if(this.lifes === 0) {
       this.$route.router.go('/ending');
      }
    }
  },
```

I find other ways like `this.router.go('/ending')` or just `router.go('/ending')` but also doesn't work.

ERROR:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "lifes": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'go' of undefined"
```

Comment: Attach the error please.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Try `this.$router.push({ path: '/ending' });`You can check the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed it.